# How do I make my discord py bot dm someone

Tags: python-3.x, discord

So I made a bot that I needed for a server and I wanted to add a command called

!dm @(user) (message)

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using discord.py 1.x and [discord.ext.commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

...  # Bot definition if this is the main file

@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message):
    await user.send(message)
```

This will need to be slightly adapted if your [Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#bot) instance variable is named something different or if it's in a [cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html).

Relevant documentation:

- [User.send()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.send)
- [Converters (how it gets a discord.User instance based on the type hint)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#discord-converters)
- [Keyword only arguments to avoid having to put quotes around the message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)